# Spotify app links

Tags: spotify

I want to be able to share links outside of spotify (facebook, twitter etc) to specific content inside my application.

My links look something like 'spotify:app:myapplication:page:58'.

I open these links with regular a-tags

```
<a href="spotify:app:myapplication:page:58">my link</a>
```

The events I have hooked are

```
sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');
models.application.observe(models.EVENT.ARGUMENTSCHANGED, function () { console.log(['ARGUMENTSCHANGED', models.application.arguments]); });
models.application.observe(models.EVENT.LINKSCHANGED, function () { console.log(['LINKSCHANGED', models.application.arguments]); });
models.application.observe(models.EVENT.ACTIVATE, function () { console.log(['ACTIVATE', models.application.arguments]); });
models.application.observe(models.EVENT.DEACTIVATE, function () { console.log(['DEACTIVATE', models.application.arguments]); });
models.application.observe(models.EVENT.CHANGE, function () { console.log(['CHANGE', models.application.arguments]); });
```

My problem is that no events are triggered when I click a link.
I can see that spotify opens the link, since it flashes in the taskbar.

Even if I type in the full link inside spotifys search-box, nothing triggers.
The only events that trigger for me is Activate/Deactivate when I leave or enter my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`models.EVENT.ARGUMENTSCHANGED` is the one you want. If the event isn't firing, there's something wrong with your code somewhere — make sure you're adding the observer when your application is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It was actually a rookie javascript mistake I had done... After your post I created a clean application with only this functionality, and then it worked... should have done that from the beginning. Thanks!